# Showing the value of a variable on a Windows form

Tags: c#

Okay I am new to programming so please bear with me. I have created a class with the following method in it.

```
public LastPrice ()
{
WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
string rawprices = wclient.DownloadString("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/");
string lastprice = rawprices.Substring(27, 5);
}
```

My question is which form control/s can I use to display the value within the lastprice variable on my form. I would like the value to keep on updating every minute or so. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Label or textbox is the normal (depending on whether it is read only or not). You can also make a textbox read only if you want the user to be able to copy the value. You'll probably want to use a timer control to handle the updating every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with JSON data, rather than trying to find the values you're looking for using string matching (eg, `.Substring()`), it would be much better to parse the data you get from the server into an object. When/if you need to work with more complicated data, then string matching will break down quickly.

Here is how you would do that:

Step 1: Reference the JSON.Net library in your project. (Right click your project in visual studio, and click "Manage NuGet packages". Search for "json.net" and then install it to your project.

Step 2: make a class that represents the data structure of the JSON you'll be getting from the server. (If this were a very complex and large data structure in JSON, then making a class for it wouldn't be practical, and there are ways around that, but for now you should get the basics down). For that JSON, a class would look like this:

```
public class Prices
{
    public decimal high { get; set; }
    public decimal last { get; set; }
    public double timestamp { get; set; }
    public decimal bid { get; set; }
    public decimal volume { get; set; }
    public decimal low { get; set; }
    public decimal ask { get; set; }
}
```

Step 3: now that you have a class, you can easily convert the JSON data into a format that's easy to work with:

```
var client = new WebClient
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8    //It's good practice to specify UTF-8 encoding, because if you don't, then you can get garbled text back from the server
};

var rawData = client.DownloadString("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/");
var btcInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Prices>(rawData);

//Now, btcInfo.last.ToString() will contain the value you're looking for.
```

Comment: Although this does not directly answer my question, thank you very much for this information.